# Interactive parameter in a report on Power BI

Tags: parameters, report, powerbi

I wanted to know if it is possible to modify a parameter directly in a report. For example, I create a field on a page where I can enter the value of the parameter and then the value displayed would be modified.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could create a numeric range slicer and read the value into a measure that can be used in visuals.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the What If Parameter feature.  It generates a disconnected table following a long-established pattern, which you can set using a Slicer and apply by referring to it in your Measure formulae.

Here's the doco:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-what-if